# Adding Google Play Services library to Qt project

Tags: java, android, qt, google-play-services

I'm creating Android application in Qt and I have to use Qt Android Extras to communicate with java code. In my java file, I'm using Google Play Services lib.

I've already done everything that is described [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/android3rdpartylibs.html). Build passes, but when i try to use something from this library, wild errors appear:

```
W/dalvikvm(28101): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/g; (169)
W/dalvikvm(28101): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/g;' failed
I/dalvikvm(28101): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.api.g.a, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.gI
W/dalvikvm(28101): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3384: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/g;.a (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/g;
```

...and believe me, there is more...

So the question is: how to add Google Play Services library to my Qt project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've managed to fix this errors by including android support library into my project by copying it from `android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4` to `PROJECT_DIR\ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR\libs` folder.